# Isomorphism between the ring $R$ and the quotient ring $R/\langle a\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with a unit element and $a$ be an element of $R$. If $R$ is isomorphic to the quotient ring $R/\langle a\rangle$, then can we conclude that $\langle a\rangle=0\,$?

If not, then what we can say about $\langle a\rangle$?

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Apparently the answer by LegNaiB was deleted. It said that the quotient map $R \longrightarrow R/(a)$ is surjective with kernel $(a)$, so it is an isomorphism iff $a = 0$.

As the answer by @LegNaiB indicated, the quotient map $R \longrightarrow R/(a)$ being an isomorphism is equivalent to $a = 0$. But you are asking if there is any isomorphism $f: R \longrightarrow R/(a)$. First of all, there is a subtle issue of if this is a isomorphism of rings or of $R$-algebras. If it is the latter, then the map $f: R \longrightarrow R/(a)$ must be the quotient map, as $f(r) = f(r*1) = r f(1) = \overline{r} f(1) = \overline{r}$ by definition of an $R$-algebra homomorphism. So in case you mean $R \cong R/(a)$ as $R$-algebras, then we must have $a = 0$.

However, if you mean to have $R \cong R/(a)$ as just rings then you need not have $a=0$. Indeed, consider the ring $R = \mathbb Z[x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots]$ with infinitely many variables. Take $a = x_1$. Then you can show that $R / (a) \cong \mathbb Z[x_2, x_3, \dots]$ via $x_1 \mapsto 0$ and $x_i \mapsto x_i$ for $i \geq 2$. Then there is an isomorphism $R \longrightarrow R/(a)$ sending $x_i \mapsto x_{i + 1}$, with inverse $x_{i} \mapsto x_{i - 1}$.

Here's a sufficient condition where you can actually show that $a = 0$. There's a fact of commutative algebra that says that if $R$ is a Noetherian local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ and $a \in \mathfrak m$ is not a zero divisor then $\dim(R / (a)) = \dim(R) - 1$. If you don't know about the Krull dimension then just know that it is an invariant of a ring. Hence, if $R \cong R/(a)$ for a Noetherian local ring $R$ with $a$ not a unit, $a$ must be a zero divisor. If $R$ is additionally assumed to be a domain, we must therefore have $a = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k$ be a field $A = k[X_0,X_1,X_2,\ldots]$ be the polynomial ring over a countable set of variables and $a = X_0$.

Then,
$$A/\langle a \rangle = k[X_1,X_2,\ldots] \simeq A$$

Comment: What if $A$ is not such a ring?

Comment: Well, there are many rings for which $A/\rangle a\langle \simeq A \Rightarrow a =0 $ does hold. I am not sure there is a simple criterion to say on which side a specific ring falls

Comment: Maybe is this true for rings with finite basis?

Comment: Finite basis is a bit vague for rings, but you can say that no quotient ring $A/I$ is isomorphic to $A$ when $A$ is Noetherian. Noetherian is a common condition on commutative rings. @LegNaiB

Comment: Yeah, I remember that Noetherian is a good finite-like property.

Answer (score 1):

If $R=\prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb Z$ is the ring whose elements are infinite sequence of integers, and, if $a=(a_i)_{i=1}^\infty, b=(b_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ then:

$$a+b=(a_i+b_i)_1^\infty\\
a\cdot b =(a_ib_i)_1^\infty.$$

Then, if $$a=(1,0,0,\cdots)$$ then w get:

$$R/\langle a\rangle \cong \prod_{i=2}^\infty\mathbb Z\cong R.$$

---

If $A$ is a Noetherian ring, then $A/I$ is not isomorphic to $A$ for any non-zero ideal $I.$

Restricting to Noetherian rings is common to exclude certain perverse cases.

This is true because if $\phi:A\to A/I$ were an isomorphism, then $I_0=\{0\}, I_{n+1}=\phi^{-1}(I_n)$ can be shown to be an infinite strictly ascending chain of ideals, which contradicts the Noetherian condition.